# Why does overwriting tty1.conf with rc.local cause a "Host SMBus controller not enabled!" hang during boot?

Tags: boot, system-installation, login, tty

I'm trying to write a new /etc/init/tty1.conf file during boot using a script that /etc/rc.local kicks off.

**Contents of /etc/rc.local:**

```
sh '/etc/first-boot-config.sh'
exit 0
```

**Line in first-boot-config.sh writing new tt1y.conf file:**

```
mv /test/tty1.conf /etc/init/
rm /test
```

**Contents of tty1.conf (purpose is to auto log on the interface user):**

```
# tty1 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] and (
            not-container or
            container CONTAINER=lxc or
            container CONTAINER=lxc-libvirt)

stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
#exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
exec /bin/login -f interface < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

**Error that appears during boot:**

```
[    2.546557] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: Host SMBus controller not enabled!
```

[image: http://imgur.com/WB7ATsT]

Anyone know what's going? The error makes no sense to me. How does changing the tty1.conf during boot, or changing one line in the tty1.conf have anything to do with the Host SMBus controller?

Also, anyone know of an easier way to make a user logon automatically during boot? Caveat: this happens during the first boot ever, there can be NO hands on keyboard. Whatever the solution is must fit into the first-boot-config.sh script. I can place any file onto the filesystem via a custom deb package so it will be on the file system when the install is done, but not /etc/tty1.conf specifically because it's already a part of another package (upstart).

**Update:** I also get this error when using Virtualbox (instead of VMWare). The Virtualbox error reads:

**Update 2:** If I restart the VM after the error appears and stops the boot... **the next boot works as expected,** auto logging in the "interface" user and kicking of it's subsequent custom shell!! **What in the heck is wrong with writing tty1.conf with rc.local then??**

```
[  175.810366] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
```

Comment: This is not an error, let alone a critical one. It doesn't say "error", for starters. Your problem is that the tty is not started, which is very much related to `tty*.conf`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my terminology in the title. Do you know of a correct way to achieve what I'm doing? If not, I'll stick with my band-aid below.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't figure out why the issue was happening but I figured out a work-around. In the same script that mv's tty1.conf into /etc/tty1.conf during the first boot ever, I added a "shutdown -r now" at the end. As long as the system is rebooted once (before or after the error that shows up), everything (including the new tty1.conf file) works as expected on next boot.

Edit: fkraiem pointed out that tty hasn't started yet at the point I'm trying to copy over tty1.conf.